# magento coupon code is behaving strangely?

Tags: coupon-codes

we are using coupon codes to give discount for customers.

we created coupon code with 50 $ discount for orders with amount less than 500 $

but when one customer buy one product and when he applied that coupon code, he get  "50 $" discount. that's fine

but when we buy 2 products , he will get less than "50 $" discount.

sometimes 26, 34, 48 $ ...etc.

any idea on what's wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: post a screenshot of your coupon configuration. Make sure you don't post the coupon code if your website is live.

Comment: @Marius I updated the question.

Comment: please show your code

Comment: @AmitBera i am using admin panel > shopping cart price rules > create coupon code, i am using default code only.

Comment: @AmitBera please check here  : http://pastebin.com/Vt8eer6B = >from app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php

Comment: i was working on another coupon code , so i kept " stop furthur rules prcessing " to = > NO.

so that's the problem it happened. coupon code was applying to only one item.

i got solution. but its really sad that one of our customer faced this problem in live site. thanks a lot Marius & Amit as always....

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the checkout page with the coupon applied and more than one item in the cart? Moreover, which magento version are you using?

Comment: @EnzoPerrotta , i got a solution , thanks a lot for your support.